# Changed motherboard now it won't read hard drive

Tags: lubuntu, drive, motherboard

I'm a bit new in this and I tried to change the motherboard but I didn't knew the risks. So now I don't know if I lost all the hard drive.

Is there something I can do? I installed the older motherboard back but it shows the same: invalid Ron contents. Welcome to emergency model, ....

I tried all the options and it always shows the initial screen of lubuntu (I run lubuntu 16.04) but then it returns to this screen.

Is there anyway I can recover the hard drive?

Regards

Comment: With the old mobo back in the case, you may be able to recover your installation.  You'll probably need to get advice from a group that is focused on your brand and model of mobo though.  Moving forward, it's always good insurance to clone your drive and use the clone if you intend to make major changes to the hardware.  That way, if you have to fall back it's not very painful.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not answering, had lot to doo. Now I see your answer. Got it fixed.